# How to extract info in the tag by looking for a tag inside of that tag?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, tags

Say I want to extract 24 min per episode info or the N13 information under Rating. Now this is just part of the code, and some of the span tags hold not `dark_text` class but something else. But when I look for tags that hold say Rating, when I find it I can't extract what Rating it is, because `N13` now is under `div` tag, not `span`, but since I'm looking for 'Rating' or 'Duration' I have to look for 'span' tag. And Beautiful Soup doesn't allow you to do `findAll('div').findAll('span', {'class':'...'})`,so I can't get back to the `div` tag if it finds the `span` tag I'm looking for.

When I do a `for` loop it prints out all these additional `None`s, among other stuff. 
Anyone has any tips on how to parse this well?

The question is really just how to look for something in `<span>` tag that is under `div` tag, but once located then extract the entire `div` tag, or maybe preferably even what is only in the `div` tag but not in the `span` tag? This has turned out to be more complicated than I anticipated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
x= '''<div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#score143583').toggle()">Overall Rating</a>:
    2
  </div>
  <div class="spaceit">
  <span class="dark_text">Duration:</span>
    24 min. per ep.
    </div>
  <div>
  <span class="dark_text">Rating:</span>
    N13
    </div>'''


bs = BeautifulSoup(x, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Could you add what your output is expected to look like?

Comment: I'm looking for either 'N13' or 'Rating: N13' and same for Duration: 24 min, and Overall Rating :2.  Not sure how to get either, but one is just div.text and the other is div.text ignoring span.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) method to get the text that is located immediately after the `span` tag. To get the `span` tag you can use `find('span', class_='dark_text', text='Duration:')`.

Creating a simple function, you can use this:

```
def get_next_text(soup, text):
    return soup.find('span', class_='dark_text', text=text).next_sibling

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
duration = get_next_text(soup, 'Duration:')
print('Duration:', duration.strip())
rating = get_next_text(soup, 'Rating:')
print('Rating:', rating.strip())
```

Output:

```
Duration: 24 min. per ep.
Rating: N13
```

If you want to get the whole `div` tag that contains the text you want, you can use [`.parent`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent).

```
def get_parent(soup, text):
    return soup.find('span', class_='dark_text', text=text).parent

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
duration = get_parent(soup, 'Duration:')
print(duration)
rating = get_parent(soup, 'Rating:')
print(rating)
```

Output:

```
<div class="spaceit">
<span class="dark_text">Duration:</span>
    24 min. per ep.
</div>
<div>
<span class="dark_text">Rating:</span>
    N13
</div>
```

Comment: I thought I might have to do smth with next sibling, thank you, this is very helpful, I'll try it out